# Need SQL to get top row

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm using a SQL Server database and have this data:

```
Loc     dept   deptdesc
-----------------------
1       201     ccccc
1       201     fffff
1       201     uuu
2       202     lllll
3       203     ooo
3       203     yyy
3       203     mmm
3       203     bbbb
```

I need help with the SQL query to get data:

```
Loc      dept      deptdesc
----------------------------
1         201        ccccc
2         202        lllll
3         203        ooo
```

Comment: It's not possible to get the result you want.  Your ordering is inconsistent.  SQL tables represent *unordered sets*, so without something to order on, the results are non-deterministic.

Comment: If you don't care about which one in the group you get, and only want one arbitrary result, that is possible.  Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: It can be any one of the dept desc. top one is fine.

Answer (score 2):

You stated in your comments that it can be any of the descriptions, assuming this is true a simple group by will work.

```
SELECT Loc, dept, MIN(deptdesc)
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY Loc, dept
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `Row_Number()` and only taking the first of each group.

```
;With Cte As
(
    Select  *, Row_Number() Over (Partition By Dept Order By (Select Null)) As RN
    From    YourTable
)
Select  Loc, Dept, DeptDesc
From    Cte
Where   RN = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below query.. You can use CTE.

```
      WITH cte_1 
       AS
        ( Select Loc,Dept,DeptDesc
               ,Row_number()over(partition by Loc,Dept Order by (select 1)) as RNO
            From YourTable)
       Select Loc,Dept,DeptDesc
       From cte_1
       Where RNO =1
```

Answer (score 0):

Have assumed there is a surrogate id

```
WITH firstVal AS(
    SELECT
        DISTINCT first_value(column4) OVER(PARTITION BY column1 ORDER BY column2 ) AS id
    FROM
    (VALUES  
        (1,201,'ccccc',100)
        ,(1,201,'fffff',101)
        ,(1,201,'uuu',102),
        (2,202,'lllll',103),
        (3,203,'ooo',104),
        (3,203,'yyy',105),
        (3,203,'mmm',106),
        (3,203,'bbbb',107)
    )
)   
SELECT  
    column1,column2,column3
FROM  
    (VALUES  
        (1,201,'ccccc',100)
        ,(1,201,'fffff',101)
        ,(1,201,'uuu',102),
        (2,202,'lllll',103),
        (3,203,'ooo',104),
        (3,203,'yyy',105),
        (3,203,'mmm',106),
        (3,203,'bbbb',107)
    ) vals
INNER JOIN firstVal ON firstVal.id = vals.column4
```